# How to trigger a stagger function in animejs in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onscroll, anime.js

I connected animejs lib to react and call it onScroll with react-visibility-sensor. I faced with the problem that I can't call **`delay: anime.stagger(1100)`** inside the object. Not sure that I explained correctly, I am newbie. Here is some code which will provide a more prominent view.

```
const IntroDiv = styled.div`
    margin-bottom: 3.5em;
    max-width: 440px;
    opacity: 0;
`;


class Intro extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);


        this.state = {
            isVisible: "false"
        }
    }

    anime = (isVisible) => {
        console.log(isVisible)
        if(isVisible){
            anime({
                targets: this.Intro,
                translateY: -30,
                duration: 800,
                easing: 'cubicBezier(.5, .05, .1, .3)',
                opacity: 1,
                delay: anime.stagger(1100)
            });
        } else console.log("kk") 
    };

    render(){
        return(
            <VisibilitySensor onChange={this.anime}>
                <IntroDiv ref={Intro => (this.Intro = Intro)}>
                    <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
                    <p>{this.props.text}</p>
                    {this.props.children}
                </IntroDiv>
            </VisibilitySensor>
        );  

    }
}

Intro.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string,
    text: PropTypes.string
}

export default Intro;
```

Comment: What is the version of animejs?

Comment: the latest one.

Comment: You code is working with v3.1.0? Do you have the same?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Anime works fine, the only thing that this part doesn't work ``delay: anime.stagger(1100)``

Comment: 1100 is just 1.1 sec, try to increase it and see the effect. The same code working at my end.

Comment: nope, still doesn't work :c